# C++ timing, milliseconds since last whole second

Tags: c++, performance, datetime

I'm working on a C++ application that needs detailed timing information, down to the millisecond level.

We intend to gather the time to second accuracy using the standard `time()` function in `<ctime>`.  We would like to additionally gather the milliseconds elapsed since the last second given by `time()`.

Does anyone know a convenient method for obtaining this information?

Answer (score 11):

Boost.DateTime has millisecond and nanosecond representations **IF** the underlying platform supports them.  While it is using platform specific code, it is keeping those details out of your code.

If that is a big deal, they do have another way of doing platform independent subsecond resolution.  [This page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_intro) a couple of paragraphs down talks about how to do it.

(From the Page)

For example, let's suppose we want to construct using a count that represents tenths of a second. That is, each tick is 0.1 second.

```
int number_of_tenths = 5;
//create a resolution independent count -- divide by 10 since there are 
//10 tenths in a second.  
int count = number_of_tenths*(time_duration::ticks_per_second()/10);
time_duration td(1,2,3,count); //01:02:03.5 //no matter the resolution settings
```

Answer (score 8):

There is not a portable solution to this problem, since ANSI C does not define a standard millisecond-accurate time function.  If you're using Windows, you can use GetTickCount(), timeGetTime(), or QueryPerformanceCounter()/QueryPerformanceFrequency().  Keep in mind that these have different accuracies and different runtime costs.

There are other similar functions in other operating systems; I'm not sure what they are off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) in Windows
[gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) in *nix
[QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) in Windows for better resolution (though GetTickCount should do it)

Answer (score 2):

**High Resolution, Low Overhead Timing for Intel Processors**

If you're on Intel hardware, here's how to read the CPU real-time instruction counter.  It will tell you the number of CPU cycles executed since the processor was booted.  This is probably the finest-grained counter you can get for performance measurement.

Note that this is the number of CPU cycles.  On linux you can get the CPU speed from /proc/cpuinfo and divide to get the number of seconds.  Converting this to a double is quite handy.

When I run this on my box, I get

```
11867927879484732
11867927879692217
it took this long to call printf: 207485
```

Here's the [Intel developer's guide](http://cs.smu.ca/~jamuir/rdtscpm1.pdf) that  gives tons of detail.

```
#include < stdio.h >  // stackoverflow bug: pre tag eats the filenames,
#include < stdint.h > // so i had to put spaces in the angle brackets

inline uint64_t rdtsc() {
    uint32_t lo, hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
      "xorl %%eax, %%eax\n"
      "cpuid\n"
      "rdtsc\n"
      : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi)
      :
      : "%ebx", "%ecx");
    return (uint64_t)hi << 32 | lo;
}

main()
{
    unsigned long long x;
    unsigned long long y;
    x = rdtsc();
    printf("%lld\n",x);
    y = rdtsc();
    printf("%lld\n",y);
    printf("it took this long to call printf: %lld\n",y-x);
}
```

Comment: The RDTSC instruction is discouraged, since it may give inaccurate results if the CPU goes to sleep, and it also does not produce consistent results between cores of a multicore system.

Comment: Those problems apply for QueryPerformanceTimer as well -- http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=106

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter() on Vista with HPET doesn't have these problems, nor does it on XP with /USEPMTIMER. AMD offers a processor driver that improves QPC() synchronization on XP. Using RDTSC directly prevents you from benefiting from any of these improvements.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Unix, **gettimeofday()** will return seconds and microseconds, up to the resolution of the system clock.

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);

struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, there is not a portable way to do this.

What I do (On msvc++ and linux/g++) is I use the following class that use QueryPerformanceCounter on Windows and gettimeofday on Linux. It's a timer class that can get you the elapsed time between two calls. You might want to modify it to fits your needs.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  define NOMINMAX // workaround un bug dans windows.h qui define des macros
                   // "min" et "max" qui entrent en conflit avec la STL.
#  include <windows.h>
#else
#  include <sys/time.h>
#endif

namespace Utils
{

   /**
    * Implémente un chronométre qui mesure le temps etre deux appels.
    */
   class CTimer
   {
   private:
#     if defined(_MSC_VER)
         LARGE_INTEGER m_depart;
#     else
         timeval m_depart;
#     endif

   public:
      /**
       * Démarre le timer.
       * 
       * Cette fonction sert à démarrer le timer. Si le timer est  déja
       * démarrer, elle le redémarre simplement.
       */
      inline void start()
      {
#        if defined(_MSC_VER)
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_depart);
#        else
            gettimeofday(&m_depart, 0);
#        endif

      };

      /**
       * Retourne le nombre de secondes depuis le départ du timer.
       * 
       * @return Nombre de secondes écoulés depuis le départ du timer
       */
      inline float GetSecondes() const
      {
#        if defined(_MSC_VER)
            LARGE_INTEGER now;
            LARGE_INTEGER freq;

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

            return (now.QuadPart - m_depart.QuadPart) / static_cast<float>(freq.QuadPart);
#        else
            timeval now;
            gettimeofday(&now, 0);

            return now.tv_sec - m_depart.tv_sec + (now.tv_usec - m_depart.tv_usec) / 1000000.0f;
#        endif
      };
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctime>

clock_t elapsed = static_cast<double>(clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

elapsed will be the elapsed processor time, in seconds.

resolution is operation system dependent, but is generally better than millisecond resolution on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

Anything not in the `(c)time.h` header requires OS-specific methods. I believe all those methods are second resolution.

What OS are you working in?

Answer (score -1):

Look into the QueryPerformanceCounter methods if this is for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Intel's [Threading Building Blocks library](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has a function for this, but TBB is currently only availble on Intel and clones (that is, it's not available on SPARCs, PowerPC, ARM, etc.)

Comment: Wow, a downvote six years after answering the question, but no explanation for the downvote.  Unfortunately, I didn't reference the function I was thinking about; it might have had something to do with `tick_count` ( https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506283 ).  Nowadays, I would use the functions in `<chrono>` ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono ).