# timespec on windows compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, elapsedtime, timespec

On posix it is possible to use timespec to calculate accurate time length (like seconds and milliseconds). Unfortunately I need to migrate to windows with Visual Studio compiler. The VS time.h library doesn't declare timespec so I'm looking for other options. As far as could search is it possible to use clock and time_t although I could't check how precise is counting millisecons with clock counting.

What do you do/use for calculating time elapse in a operation (if possible using standards c++ library) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is usually used for that.

Also a similiar thread: [C++ timing, milliseconds since last whole second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117346/c-timing-milliseconds-since-last-whole-second)

Comment: Is there a way to use standards c++ library. It would be a bonus. I forgot to mention that as well

Comment: Check this thread, it contains an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117346/c-timing-milliseconds-since-last-whole-second

Comment: Thanks @Grim. It seen that this isn't portable

Comment: The boost solution on the referenced thread is probably your most portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what sort of accuracy you want, my understanding is that clock and time_t are not  accurate to the millisecond level. Similarly GetTickCount() is commonly used  (MS docs say accurate to 10-15ms) but not sufficiently accurate for many purposes.

I use [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for accurate timing measurements for performance.

Comment: `time_t` is accurate to one second, as it is an integer type representing seconds; subsecond accuracy is not mathematically possible.

Comment: So I will stay stuck to the compiler

Comment: Actually you will be stuck with Windows API not the compiler.