# struct timespec not working in MSVC 2015 for x64 build

Tags: c

```
#include <time.h>
struct timespec first_tm1;
int ts_compare(struct timespec *time1, struct timespec *time2)
{
if (time1->tv_sec < time2->tv_sec)
    return -1; /* Less than. */
}
```

It gives the following :

> Error  C2079   'first_tm1' uses undefined struct 'timespec'
>
> Error  C2037   left of 'tv_sec' specifies undefined struct/union 'timespec'

Comment: I have voted to close, because normal things don't work in MSVC, and there are a few questions about this specifically, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188907/timespec-on-windows-compilers

Comment: here is a reference where they got it to work with external GNU library: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/63

Comment: Posix is not Windows and is not C.  Using all lowercase letters and no leading underscore hides that pretty well for everybody it seems :)  Use a [standard C library function instead](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/).

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @HansPassant: `struct timespec` is standard C.

Comment: Just add here, this code is compile & working fine in x86 configuration. Not compiling in x64 configuration

Comment: I am facing compilation error for Debug build only (release build ok). 
Error C2079 'first_tm' uses undefined struct 'timespec' testbot C:\Users\sghorai\development\my-first-driver\logger.c 325